# Java | int Method | I need ELSE {Return nothing}

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, return

I've come across a situation where I need to use a method to check if the sum of the two digits of a number from 10 to 50 is larger than 10 and then display that number. I must use a for loop.

This is my main:

```
public class nested_loop2 
{ 
public static void main(String args[])  
{ 
    for (int i=10;i<=50;i++){
       System.out.println(ax(i));       
    }
}
```

This is my method:

```
   public static int ax(int i){
       int a=i/10;
       int b=i%10;
       if((a+b)>10){
           return i; 
       }
       else { 
          return 0;
       }
    }
 }
```

The problem I have with this is that I want it to display only those particular numbers that pass the verification. In the current state, it also prints out 0 for all the ones that didn't fit. I don't want it to return 0, I just want it to not return anything for the else{} statement.

Comment: Could it be as simple as replacing the line in the loop with "if (ax(i) > 0) System.out.println(ax(i));" ? Sure you call the method twice, but does it matter?

Comment: What is this algorithm used for?

Comment: It's to check if the sum of the two digits of a number from 10 to 50 is larger than 10 and then display that number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only information you need to return in your `ax` method is whether the sum of digits is larger than `10`.  Incidentally, the name `ax` doesn't describe what your method does.  Perhaps you could use `sumOfDigitsGreaterThan10`.

You don't need to return an `int`; you can return a `boolean`.  Instead of returning `i`, return `true`.  Instead of returning `0`, return `false`.

Then in your `main` method, use an `if` statement testing this returned `boolean` to determine whether to print the number.

Alternatively, you could make that method `ax` print the number itself if the sum of the digits is greater than 10, and not printing anything in the `else` case.  This method would now return `void`.

Comment: That sounds like a very practical way to go about it. Thank you.

Comment: One final thought: Would there be no other way to use an int method for this?

Comment: This is the right idea. It's best to strive for single purpose methods. Also, it'd be worthwhile to come up with some more meaningful method names at least.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way around this would just to print the number in the function. It would look like this:

Main:

```
public static void main(String args[])  
{ 
    for (int i=10;i<=50;i++){
        ax(i);
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public static void ax(int i){
    int a=i/10;
    int b=i%10;
    if((a+b)>10){System.out.println(i);}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `ax()` is already designed to return the `int` if it satisfies the condition, just check if the returned result is greater than 0.  If so, print it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 10; i <= 50; i++) {
        if (ax(i) > 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

public static int ax(int i) {
    int a = i / 10;
    int b = i % 10;
    if ((a + b) > 10) {
        return i;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
29
38
39
47
48
49
```

From here, you can decide to optimize/reduce/redesign the code to produce the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can also return -1 instead of 0 and then check

```
if(ax(i) != -1){
     print i
}
```

Comment: Why can't you leave the return statement as is and just check if the returned value is 0 or not?